# Learning the boolean AND function using a perceptron

Tags: java, machine-learning, perceptron

I'm new to machine learning. I've written this code http://ideone.com/t9VOag for training a perceptron to learn the boolean AND function using the perceptron training rule.

The perceptron never learnes the correct weights. Errors for input (1, -1) and (-1, 1) make the weights to oscillate between 0.7999999999999999, 0.20000000000000004 and 0.7, 0.300000000000000 which is obvious as

```
For input 1, -1


target output - output given = 0-1 = -1

w1 = w1 + n*(t-o)*1 = w1 - n

w2 = w2 + n*(t-o)*(-1) = w2 + n


for input -1, 1

t-o = 0-1 = -1

w1 = w1 + (n)(t-o)(-1) = w1 + n

w2 = w2 + (n)(t-o)(1) = w2 - n

The weights are getting increased and decreased by the same amount
```

If I include the weight w0 for being updated during learning, it reaches a solution (but w0 isn't supposed to be updated?).

What is the correct implementation?

Comment: this is not valid java code

Comment: the java code is in the link mentioned in the question.

Comment: you need to make sure the training data is linearly separable. i have not checked your input but this could be a problem

Comment: I've used training data for the AND boolean function which is linearly separable.

Answer (score 0):

Take w0 out of the code altogether. Your perceptron should have 2 input nodes and 1 output node with a single weight connecting each input node to the output node. Like this (excuse the bad ascii art):

```
I1
   \
    \W1
     \ 
      Out
     /
    /W2
   /
I2
```

You are effectively feeding in a strong bias by setting `W0` to 1

Comment: If I take out w0, it reaches a solution but if the bias is set to any value, the weights oscillate.

Comment: Why do you want a bias? You shouldn't need one.

Comment: I tried different w1 and w2 values taking out the bias, it still oscillates between weight values in some cases.

Comment: what do you mean in some cases? Are you always training it on AND?

Comment: I mean for some pair of random values of w1 and w2.

Comment: you mean random `initial` values?

Comment: You're checking for exact equality between `target` and `output`. That will only happen for some values of `n` for any given initial values for `w1` and `w2`.

Comment: change `if(t==o)` to `if(t - o < theta)` and set `theta` to a small value (but larger than `n`). That should make your perceptron converge.

Comment: target (t) and output (o) are only having values 0 or 1. when these are equal, we know the example has been correctly classified. When all the four training inputs are correctly classified t == 0 in all the 4 inputs, the training is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to your statement "*but w0 isn't supposed to be updated*", w0 is supposed to be updated, however, input to w0 is always your unchangable bias (for example 1).

Intuition: Look at your problem; you have two inputs could be either 1 or -1 and they could change their positions without affecting the result. This is the nature of "and" operator. Therefore, w1 should be equal to w2 and bias weight (w0) should be zero.

Briefly, your code is correct and you should just uncomment updating w0.